# How to modify & replace the key an object by comparing it with other objects?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have an array of object which consists some id's as a key.

```
const sampleObj1 = {0011:[{},{}], 0022:[{}, {}], 0033:[{},{}]}
const sampleObj2 = [{id:0011, name:'test1'}, {id:0022, name:'test2'}, {id:0033, name:'test3'}]
```

I want to compare sampleObj1 key with the sampleObj2 id value and then need to create new obj some like below.

```
const newObjByComparing = {test1:[{},{}], test2:[{},{}], test3:[{},{}]} //desired result
```

I have tried using for loop but not able to get the desired compared value.

```
const fromRdx = sampleObj2; 
const fromApi = sampleObj1; 
const keys = Object.keys(fromApi);
const newObjAfterComparision = {};

for (let i in fromRdx) {
    newObjAfterComparision[fromRdx[i]] = fromApi[keys[i]];
    fromApi[fromRdx[i]] = fromApi[keys[i]];
    delete fromApi[keys[i]];
}

console.log(newObjAfterComparision)
```

Comment: sampleObj2 not valid object

Comment: @cmgchess i have updated sampleObj2  obj.

Comment: May I please understand if `sampleObj2` is an object - because, it does appear like an `Array` (since it has no key-value pairs, and only array elements).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below may be one possible solution to achieve the desired objective:

**Code Snippet**

```js
const transformObj = (obj, arr) => arr.reduce((f, i) => ({
  ...f,
  [i.name]: obj[i.id]
}), {});

const sampleObj = {
  "0011": [{}, {}],
  "0022": [{}, {}],
  "0033": [{}, {}]
};
const sampleArr = [{
  id: "0011",
  name: "test1"
}, {
  id: "0022",
  name: "test2"
}, {
  id: "0033",
  name: "test3"
}];

console.log(transformObj(sampleObj, sampleArr));
```

**Expalanation**

- Use `.reduce()` to iterate over the `sampleArr`
- For each element populate a result obj (named `f`)
- The key of the object will be the element's `name` and value will be the value from the `sampleObj` (where key is element's `id`)

Answer (score 1):

Another approach using `map` and `Object.fromEntries`

```js
const sampleObj1 = {'0011':[{},{}], '0022':[{}, {}], '0033':[{},{}]}
const sampleObj2 = [{id:'0011', name:'test1'}, {id:'0022', name:'test2'}, {id:'0033', name:'test3'}]


let y = Object.fromEntries(sampleObj2.map(({id,name}) => [name,sampleObj1[id]]))

console.log(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

**I Have a simple solution for you**

```
const sampleObj1 = {0011:[{},{}], 0022:[{}, {}], 0033:[{},{}]}
const sampleObj2 = [{id:0011, name:'test1'}, {id:0022, name:'test2'}, {id:0033, name:'test3'}]

const keys = Object.keys(sampleObj1);
const newObjByComparing = sampleObj2.reduce((acc, cur, index) => {
    acc[cur.name] = sampleObj1[keys[index]];
    return acc;
}, {});
```